# How to get the totalResults entry from the YouTube video API

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm using PHP and the YouTube API to get videos from YouTube to feed to my web app, but I don't know how to get the `totalResults` entry

Here is my code:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setQuery($searchTerm);
$query->setStartIndex($startIndex);
$query->setMaxResults($maxResults);
$feed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query);

echo $feed->totalResults; // this desn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element itself is protected; you need to use the [getTotalResults](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Gdata/Zend_Gdata_Feed.html#getTotalResults) accessor:

```
echo $feed->getTotalResults();
```

Comment: thanks! it works:
<pre>
echo $feed->getTotalResults()->text;
</pre>